# .Net remoting & client locked but displays no error

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, remoting

Both client and server are on the same machine.

On server side, I build my remote object within a separate thread (its isn't the main thread) :

```
Private _remoteObject as RemoteObject
...

'Just one time :
Dim tc as TcpChannel = New TcpChannel(1002)
ChannelServices.registerChannel(tc, false)
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(IRemoteObject),  "RemoteServerObject", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall)
RemotingServices.Marshal(_remoteObject, "RemoteServerObject")
...
_remoteObject = new RemoteObject()
_remoteObject.RemoteOtherObjects.Add(New RemoteOtherObject(_property1, _property2))
```

Client side :

```
Private _remoteObject as Remoting.IRemoteObject
...
'One time
Dim tcpChannel As New TcpChannel()
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, false)
Dim _remoteObject as IRemoteObject
_remoteObject = Activator.GetObject(GetType(RemotingObject.IRemoteObject), "tcp://localhost:1002/RemoteServerObject")
While True
   Thread.Sleep(1000)
   Dim remoteOtherObject as IRemoteOtherObject = _remoteObject.GetRemoteOtherObjectByName("testName")
   For Each property2 as IProperty2 In remoteOtherObject.Properties2
       Console.WriteLine(property2.someting)
   Next
End While
```

All sub-objects of the class **RemoteObject** inherits **MarshalByRefObject**.
The client only see an interface of **RemoteObject** (separate dll).

My problem is, in the for **each loop at client side, I have no error**, it is just locked, my *console is responding but nothing is written*.

Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: Something else to improve my question : I've tried to pass by Singleton or SingleCall, the same problem appears.

Comment: Looks like the server doesn't give the time for the client to get the object.

Comment: In client side, my objects are well retrieved, they are on TransparentProxy form. It seems that there is a problem transforming them to real proxy / objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a problem of conflict between the two prompts.
The one for the server side used the same UI thread of the client one, which was not refreshed.